# What subsets of $\mathbb R$ can we speak of uniform continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

From Ross's *Elementary Analysis*:

> [image]
>
> [image]

---

The set $S$ can be an interval. But can it be a singleton? Can it contain isolated points such as $S = [2,4] \cup \{6\}$?

---

Note: I'm not sure if this is relevant but this particular elementary real analysis book doesn't cover much of isolated points, limit points, open sets, closed sets, etc. I think it's in a chapter with an * (which I'm guessing means optional), but I notice that it avoids using terms such as interior, open set, etc unlike other books such as [Lay - Analysis With An Introduction to Proof](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032174747X) or [Trench - Introduction to Real Analysis](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF)

Comment: $S$ can be a singleton. But in that case it's not very interesting. What they're saying is that uniform continuity is something that is satisfied on all of $S$ at the same time, or not at all. They are not any way limiting what $S$ can be.

Comment: @Arthur So $S$ may have isolated points?

Comment: @BLCC: Abbott's point is, uniform continuity is a global property, not local. A function can be _locally constant_ yet not uniformly continuous: think of $f(x) = x/|x|$ on the set of non-zero real numbers.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I guess I'll have to revise more. Thanks! ^-^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the title:

> What subsets of $\mathbb R$ can we speak of uniform continuity?

For *any* subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Reading definition 19.1 carefully, you would find that there is *no* restriction on $S$.

What confuses you might be in the second box. "It makes no sense to speak of a function being uniformly continuous at each point." What it really means is the following:

Suppose $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real function. It makes no sense to speak of $f$ being uniformly continuous at *some* $x\in S$. It is not that $S$ cannot be a singleton.

Comment: I guess I'll have to revise more. Thanks Jack! ^-^